# как поставить обьект в вниз до конца

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу поставить изображение в конец вниз попоробовал clear получилось поставить вниз но изображение не закрепляется в display: fixed;
Html

```
 <div id="lft">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/settings.png"></a>
    </div>
```

css

```
#lft{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 75, 144);
    position: fixed;
}
#lft img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Приведите визуальный или хотя бы схематический пример того, что Вы хотели бы видеть в итоге

Comment: я хочу чтобы lft img был самым внизу закрепленный на lft чтоб при прокрутки страниц этот img оставался на месте как lft

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что ещё будет или не будет лежать рядом с изображением. Ну если "пальцем в небо", то или добавьте для `#lft img` стили `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` или же для `#lft` что-то в этом роде: `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-end;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на слепую(не имея и малейшего представления об остальной верстке) как то так...

```css
#root{height: 300vh;}

#lft{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 75, 144);
    position: fixed;
}
#lft img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 0;              /*!!!!!!!!*/
    position: fixed;        /*!!!!!!!!*/
}
```

```html
<div id='root'>
  <div id="lft">
   <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

если не сработает, остальную верстку прикрепите наконец(это стоило сделать изначально)

Comment: Спасибо это то что я хотел